# vertically align images inside a bootstrap navbar to the baseline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Given the following navbar declaration, I need the images below aligned to the bottom of the bootstrap navbar. I have a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/6CP3KZU9IU) which clearly demonstrates that they are all aligned top.

I have tried setting the `li` elements to `vertical-align: baseline`, but alas it's not enough.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top affix-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-right">
                <a href="">info@link.com</a>
                <a href="">INFO</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="border: 1px solid black">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="FIRST IMAGE"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="SECOND IMAGE"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="THIRD IMAGE"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use class="align-baseline"> on the lines

Comment: I tried align-baseline, didn't seem to do the trick http://www.bootply.com/H5FODh9GjC#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vertical-align` will only work on table cells (for it's children) or inline elements (on themselves).

With that in mind, you can change the `li` to `inline-block` elements and vertical align them:

```
.navbar-nav li {float:none; display:inline-block; vertical-align:bottom;}
```

[Updated pen](http://www.bootply.com/Kk1OmqEf00)

Answer (score 1):

Two things have to be changed. The line-height must be increased to the height of your tallest image, and the images must be `vertical-align: bottom;`

```
.navbar-nav li a {
    line-height: 70px;
}

.navbar-nav li img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/rnfCHaf7R9